# How to trigger Google Apps script when user makes a copy

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I want to clear some range content from a sheet when someone creates a copy of that g-sheet.

How can I make the "create a copy" menu item, trigger a script?

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific here: `I want to clear user data from a sheet when someone creates a copy of that g-sheet.` What kind of data are you looking for to delete?

Comment: There is no trigger for that event

Comment: @Marios clear some range content from a sheet

Comment: @Cooper Any workarround? Maybe blocking regular "make a copy" and make it thrrough script only?

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the "make a copy" menu item and allow it only by a script.

```
function makeACopy() {
  clearRange("A1:A100");
  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById('FileId').makeCopy().getId();
  DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('PT generator' + new Date() );
};

function clearRange(rangeToClear) {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    const formulas = sheet.getRange(rangeToClear).getFormulas();

    sheet.getRange(rangeToClear).clear({
        contentsOnly: true,
        skipFilteredRows: false
    });
    sheet.getRange(rangeToClear).setFormulas(formulas)
};
```